# Very strange 16.04 wired internet connectivity issues

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, dns

I'm having a strange problem with internet connectivity in my fresh ubuntu install on a new PC build with a H110N motherboard (I don't know if that matters). This is my first time using linux as my main OS so please bare with me.

So I originally tried installing Fedora but was having some strange issues with my internet connection. It seems like I can resolve and connect to some large websites (Eg. Google.com, youtube.com, facebook.com, and fast.com which is owned by netflix) but not much else.

I decided to switch to ubuntu hoping it would solve the problem and it hasn't. I can ping google.com, but I get 100% packet loss trying to ping 8.8.8.8. Furthermore, I can make a google search, but any link I try to click on there just loads infinitely.

The weird thing is I can run apt-get fine, and the software center seems to be working. I was able to install exfat-utils and chromium through both respectively.

Any help would be really appreciated because I'd like to learn what's going on here and finish up my setup! If you need anymore information please just tell me what you need. Thanks

EDIT: Requested ping results of a problem website.

```
ping -c10 reddit.com
PING reddit.com (151.101.65.140) 56(84) bytes of data.
---reddit.com ping statistics---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 9070ms
```

Comment: What is the output of `dig www.google.com | egrep SERVER`?

Comment: `;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)`

Comment: Edit your `/etc/resolv.conf` file and put this for the first server: `nameserver 8.8.8.8`.  Then try your application and see if you have he same weird issue.

Comment: yup, still have the same issues.

Comment: Will you update your question and add the output of `ping` to one of the sites you have a problem with.  `ping -c10 problemsite.com`?  Also, does the result return the same at it does when you ping 8.8.8.8?

Comment: The question has been updated with those stats

Comment: I'm looking for a method to test if there are firewalls in the router blocking some sites.  Do you own the router?  Also is it possible to set your phone to a temporary hotspot and connect to it and see if you have the same problem?  If you have a smart phone many providers will allow a very small connection fee about $3.00 for a day, or $10.00 for a month's tethering.  I'll let you know of a more direct method of checking it it's the router blocking the sites.

Comment: I've already tested it with a USB tether with my phone. It works and I can load all sites. However one thing to mention is that my current router is an Apple Time Capsule. I've been wanting to replace it because apple is infuriating, but haven't. Ive been looking online and nobody seems to have any problems with comparability between GNU/Linux and those routers.

Comment: Are you able to access the sites using your phone connected to the router for internet?

Comment: If I tether my phone to my desktop all sites load. Loading sites on my phone works as well too

Comment: The problem may be related to how your Apple Time Capsule is processing IPv6 connections.  I'll provide you formatted steps in a formatted answer to disable IPv6 on your computer.

Comment: Do you think I should try wiring directly to the modem first? If the router is the problem, this will be the straw the breaks the camels back and I'll replace it.

Comment: I didn't know you had that option.  But that would be a quick way to verify it's the access point (the Apple Time Capsule) that is the culprit.

Comment: Alright I'll do that tomorrow and give an update. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure thing... I'll just update the details in the meantime.  Reply and test when it's convenient for you.

Comment: I disabled IPv6 and I'm still having the same issue. I ended up buying a new router anyway because this one has been giving me problems with wireless for a while. I'm not so sure it is the router though because I hard wired the desktop to the modem via ethernet and was able to load no web pages at all. Ideas?

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging the problematic router part.  As mentioned in the answer, there is a chance the manufacturer may have a fix.  Glad you're up and running.

Comment: I'm far from up and running. The IPv6 trick didn't solve the issue. I tried hard wiring to the modem very briefly and was unable to get an internet connection at all. I'll have to fiddle with it more later today

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said you were saying you replaced the Time Capsule.

Comment: I've ordered a replacement. It comes on Friday. I'm hoping that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem, from the results of the test in the comments, is your access point connection.  The immediate resolution is to bypass the Apple Time Capsule and connect directly to the modem.

Using and configuring the Apple Time Capsule router will have to be configured to properly handled by supporters of the hardware.

It's the failure to load certain sites is a common problem with users of the device as a [apple time capsule some sites fail to load](https://www.google.com/#q=apple+time+capsule+some+sites+fail+to+load)  search reveals.

Some report it as a faulty device.

There are two things you can try, which includes resetting the device to factory reset and disabling IPv6 on your computer.

You can disable IPv6 on your computer with:

Edit your `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and append this to the bottom:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Then run this:

```
$ sudo sysctl -p
```

You can verify that IPv6 is disabled with:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```

The output will be:

```
1
```

Now load your site.

If at some time you decide to reenable IPv6 just remove the appended lines added to the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file.