# sudo apt-get update stuck at 0% [Working]

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates

Running `sudo apt-get update` always get's stuck on `0% [Working]`
Here's an example log:

```
➜  ~ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu xenial 
InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                                                                                
Hit:3 http://repo.entroware.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                          
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                          
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed InRelease                                                                                
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu xenial 
InRelease                             
Hit:8 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                            
Hit:9 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease    
Hit:10 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
0% [Working]
```

It tends to get stuck on the same step multiple times in a row, but tends to change which step that is.

I've tried forcing IPv4 as well as changing to the default mirror with no success. I also can't seem to find any logs for this as tailing the `/var/log/apt/term.log` doesn't give me anything.

One thing to note is that switching mirror also changed the step it got stuck at.

Comment: Does network works well? Did you try to ping something to see if it can reach any external server?

Comment: I've tried pinging gb.archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com successfully. I don't thing the network is the issue. I've tried 3 different networks just to be sure.

Comment: Disable **ipv6**.  Details of how is described in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/876021)

Comment: Thanks, but still no progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It ended up being a problem with one of the sources. Specifically removing this line from `/etc/apt/sources.list` fixed it: `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable`.

After that I ran clean, autoclean and followed this [guide](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) which added the same source back in after which point it continued working.

Hopefully this will be useful if someone encounters the same problem.

Comment: so marking this as solution resp. accepted answer would make sense!

Comment: And how did you figure out which source was at fault? This answer is uninformative.

Comment: @Pithikos Informed assumptions + trial and error, I guess I could have made it explicit. In any case I don't have something I'd describe as a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem, ran `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`. Was no `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable`.

Generated standard sources from [here](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and replaced in the `sources.list`.

Comment: and what happened then?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens it continues the process to the end and prints "AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors."

Comment: Three lines of the messages are: 
"W: GPG error: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A2F683C52980AECF
W: The repository 'http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian xenial InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use."